# Rails 5 find_or_create still creating duplicates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I have a 'gin' model that allows nested attributes for 'name' in a 'distillery' model.  The nested form is working well, but I realised I'm creating 'duplicate' distillery entries.  It seems 'find_or_create_by' should prevent this, **but I can't get it to not create a duplicate.**

As this is a nested form, I'm also unsure which controller I should place it.

This is what I have so far, and as mentioned this continues to create multiple records for a distillery.  I don't have any errors.

**gins_controller.rb**

```
class GinsController < ApplicationController

...
  def new
    @gin = Gin.new
    @gin.build_distillery
  end
```

**distillery_controller.rb**

```
class DistilleriesController < ApplicationController
 ...
  def new
    @distillery = Distillery.find_or_create_by(name: 'name')
  end
```

**gins_form**

```
<%= form.fields_for :distillery do |distillery_form| %>
  <p>
    <%= distillery_form.label :distillery, class: "block text-grey-darker text-sm font-bold mb-2" %>
    <%= distillery_form.text_field :name, class:"lg:w-2/5 w-full shadow appearance-none border rounded py-2 px-3 mb-6 text-grey-darker" %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

**update**

have moved this to the gins_controller but it doesn't solve it:

```
  def new
    @gin = Gin.new
    @gin.build_distillery
    @distillery = Distillery.find_or_create_by(name: 'name')
  end
```

Comment: Could you add the gins_form?

Comment: gins form added @Tobias

Comment: If you're submitting the distillery as part of the `Gin`, then you'd need to do the `find_or_create_by` in the `GinsController`, not the `DistilleryController`. Also, in `DistilleryController` you should not be creating a distillery in the `new` action, that's what the form that `new` renders would be for.

Comment: thanks, @dinjas.  I've moved it into the gins controller, but I'm still creating duplicates, unfortunately.

Comment: @SimonCooper what does the `create` action in your GinsController look like?

Comment: @SimonCooper, you don't need `@distillery` in the new action of GinsController. In the create action you need to separately build Gin from params, and after it use something like `@gin.distillery = Distillery.find_or_create_by(name: params[:name])`

Answer (score 2):

The `new` method is used to create a new object to be shown in the view (the form to input data to create a record in the database). But the `new` method does not save the object to the database. So it makes no sense to use **find_or_create** in `new` method. Just use **new** or **build**.

You should use `find_or_create` in the **create** method, where the record is in fact created an saved.

Another approach is that you define distillery name as a unique field, so you cannot create duplicate distilleries.

A third option is that you select distilleries in the form using a select field (this requires that distilleries are created before creating gin). In general, this should be the best approach: if Gin belongs_to :distillery (I'm assuming), it's better to select the distillery than to enter a name in a field. If you make a typo, you will be creating a new distillery instead of using an existing one.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Pablo.
Here's an idea of how to implement the new/create methods were you to leave most of your code the same

```
 def new
    @gin = Gin.new
    @gin.build_distillery
 end
 def create
    @gin = Gin.new(gin_params)
    @gin.distillery = Distillery.find_or_create_by(name: distillery_name)
    @gin.save! # oversimplification - you probably have respond blocks
 end

 def distillery_name
   params[:distillery][:name] # or however it really is
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not specify this, I am assuming your associations look as follows:

```
class Gin
  belongs_to :distillery 

class Distillery
  has_many :gins
```

Now in general, what you would do in that case is just select a distillery from a drop-down list. So we will set the link (`distillery_id`) directly, so we do not need `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in the model `Gin`.

If you are using simple-form gem, this is as easy as

```
 f.association :distillery
```

or using normal forms, you could write something like

```
f.collection_select :distillery_id, Distillery.all, :id, :name, {include_blank: true}
```

Up until now you do not have to do anything special on the controller-side: when saving the form it sets the distillery-id and this will create the link. But it also assumes the distilleries already exist (which in most cases will be the case).

It gets a little more complicated when you want to be able to link to an existing distillery *or* create a new distillery in one form.

A really simple solution for this would be to write your form as follows:

```
= f.collection_select :distillery_id, Distillery.all, :id, :name, {include_blank: true}
= text_field_tag :distillery_name
```

(for optimal user experience you would add some js sprinkles to make sure a user would either select something from the drop-down OR fill in the name)

And then in your controller you can do something like

```
def create
  if params[:gin][:distillery_id].blank? && params[:distillery_name].present?
    @distillery = Distillery.find_or_create_by(name: params[:distillery_name])
    params[:gin][:distillery_id] = @distillery.id 
  end 
  gin = Gin.build(gin_params) 
  [... the rest of your create method as before ...]
```

So in short:

- we check if the user has *not* selected a distillery from the drop-down (if yes, just use it instead) *and* a new name has been given
- using the given name, try to find the distillery or create a new one
- fill the distillery id in the form
- then just save the form data as before